# I can't login to my samba shares

Tags: samba

I've been using samba for years without any problems, I have configured some shares that won't ask for password (guest ok) ... unfortunately I've updated the packages on the server (Ubuntu 14.04.4 TLS) and after that, I cannot longer access them, it keeps asking me for a password.

The new samba version is 4.3.8+dfsg-0ubuntu ... this is broken somehow, anyone knows how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there's a bug in the latest samba version:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/samba/+bug/1572876?comments=all

For the moment, the only workaround I found was to remove samba and then install the previous packages using:

```
apt-get install samba=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2 samba-common=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2 samba-libs=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2 samba-common-bin=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2 samba-dsdb-modules=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2 python-samba=2:4.1.6+dfsg-1ubuntu2 libldb1=1:1.1.16-1 python-ldb=1:1.1.16-1
```